# How do I make my HTML5 layout compatible with IE? (ActiveX Blocked?)

Tags: internet-explorer, html, activex

What can I do to stop ActiveX on IE from blocking scripts on my HTML5 layout?

Comment: Can you include some code? How is ActiveX blocking your scripts?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the opener's real question is: "*I'm opening a HTML file from my desktop. IE blocks the script in it. Why and how do I stop that?*"

The answer is that this is controlled by the setting of the Tools > Internet Options > Advanced > "Allow Active Content to Run in files on my local computer" checkbox. That controls an important IE security feature called "Local Machine Lockdown" that prevents local scripts from running until you click the bar.

The recommended approach to resolve, rather than changing the box, is to add a "Mark of the Web" to your file. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537628(VS.85).aspx

Comment: And if my file is hosted, will it go away?

Comment: If you add the Mark of the Web and the warning goes away, then yes, the warning will not appear when your file is hosted on a Internet-zone web server.

Answer (score 1):

What feature of HTML5 are you using?

You can also rename your file (when testing locally) to .hta which will make it an HTML application. HTA files have more privileges than the HTM/HTML files, and can run active content on Local Machine by default.